# Using Ionic Native APIs with Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to incorporate https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/battery-status/ into an app I am building with Ionic v2.

I have followed the usage instructions from the above URL and here is my profile.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BatteryStatus } from 'ionic-native';
import { StatusObject } from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfilePage {

  public level: number;  
  public isPlugged: boolean;    

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    let subscription = BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe(
        (status: StatusObject) => {
            this.level = status.level;
            this.isPlugged = status.isPlugged;
        }
    );

    subscription.unsubscribe();

  }

}
```

This works on ionic serve and I have built a version to run on my iPhone.

In my template I have:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>    
    <ion-title>profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

    <p>{{ level }}</p>
    <p>{{ isPlugged }}</p>

</ion-content>
```

But nothing appears. How can I actually display the level and whether the phone is plugged in?

Comment: You haven't imported that name; either import it, or don't type the parameter.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to add a comment with an example of what I am missing?

Comment: Well you see how you e.g. `import { BatteryStatus } ...`? Find `StatusObject` and import that too

Comment: I have added import { StatusObject } from 'ionic-native'; and the error has gone ... although I don't actually see anything in my view. I'll update my original post ...

Comment: Have you tried removing `subscription.unsubscribe();`? Maybe you are running into a race condition. Does `BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe` ever get fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chris, the problems seems to be in your constructor, you are subscribing to the onChange event and right after that unsubscribing from it.
Different from BehaviourSubject, an Observable - which is what onChange() returns - only fires on a new value, this means that you won't get any value from it until it fires a new event, and that is probably not going to happen between those two lines of code, just as @Jorge mentions on his comment.

To fix this I suggest you move the unsubscribe to a new function called ngOnDestroy(), this is a angular function that gets called upon a component's destruction. Just like below:

```
export class ProfilePage {

    public level: number;  
    public isPlugged: boolean;   
    public onChangeSub: Subscription; 

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

        let subscription = BatteryStatus.onChange().subscribe(
            (status: StatusObject) => {
                this.level = status.level;
                this.isPlugged = status.isPlugged;
            }
        );

    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

This will keep your subscription active during the lifecycle of the component, reflecting changes in the HTML.

Hope it helps